# How to remove an entry from named.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a bind daemon that was used to resolve a domain. But now i want to use another nameserver. I tried to remove the entry for that domain from the named.conf file, removed also the zone file and restarted the daemon. But it seems that there is no effect.

Is there anything i can do more? I am begginer in dns configuration so this may be noob question but i could not find an answer on google.

UPDATE: this is what dig + trace gives

```
;; global options: +cmd
.                       63224   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       63224   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
;; Received 512 bytes from 193.231.169.2#53(193.231.169.2) in 1 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 506 bytes from 192.112.36.4#53(g.root-servers.net) in 55 ms

rencontres-selection.com. 172800 IN     NS      nssec.dedibox.fr.
rencontres-selection.com. 172800 IN     NS      sd-18368.dedibox.fr.
;; Received 99 bytes from 192.26.92.30#53(c.gtld-servers.net) in 124 ms

www.rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN CNAME   rencontres-selection.com.
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN     A       88.191.110.117
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN     NS      sd-18368.dedibox.fr.
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN     NS      nssec.dedibox.fr.
;; Received 145 bytes from 88.191.108.117#53(sd-18368.dedibox.fr) in 43 ms
```

Comment: Could you give more specifics, particularly about why you think it's had no effect?  Unredacted output is particularly helpful in such cases.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is dedibox.fr the domain you are trying to remove? From what server are you trying to remove it?

Comment: sd-18368.dedibox.fr is the server . The domain i try to remove is another one, rencontres-selection.com. My question is how can do that sd-18368.dedibox.fr is no longer listed as NS for rencontres-selection.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Dan, in the light of what you've said above, here's what I get when I do the same thing:

```
[madhatter@risby madhatter]$ dig www.rencontres-selection.com
  [...]
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.rencontres-selection.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN CNAME   rencontres-selection.com.
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN A   88.191.110.117

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN NS  sd-18368.dedibox.fr.
rencontres-selection.com. 604800 IN NS  nssec.dedibox.fr.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
nssec.dedibox.fr.   7200    IN  A   88.191.254.71
sd-18368.dedibox.fr.    86400   IN  A   88.191.108.117
```

That seems to be what you get.  Can you say why you think your local named is still behaving as if it's authoritative?

**Later**: from what you've written above, it's possible that your underlying complaint is that the internet is still treating `sd-18368.dedibox.fr` as authoritative for the domain.

According to [the registrar's whois page](https://www.ovh.com/fr/cgi-bin/tools/check_whois.pl), the listed name servers for the domain are

```
Name Server: NSSEC.DEDIBOX.FR
Name Server: SD-18368.DEDIBOX.FR
```

If you want to stop the internet looking to `sd-18368.dedibox.fr` you will need to change the glue records at your registrar.  This is **not** something you can fix via named.conf, it must be done through the registrar.  You will also need to change the NS records listed in the zone file on the master server, which I presume is `nssec.dedibox.fr`.

Is that any help?